# Compiling error: to_string is not a member of std

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors, std, g++4.8

My code is something like this:

```
#include <string>
int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        std::string flag = "I got a number like : " + std::to_string(i);
    }
}
```

When I try to compile it on my FreeBSD 9.2 machine with g++ 4.8.2 I get the following error:

`error: 'to_string' is not a member of 'std'`
`std::string flag = "I got a number like : " + std::to_string(i);`

Yes I am using the `-std=c++11` and no I'm not using minGW

Compile line: `g++48 -g -std=c++11 -Wall -O2 -m32 -pipe -fexceptions -D_THREAD_SAFE -DNDEBUG -mtune=i686 -fstack-protector-all`

Comment: You need the `-std=c++11` flag. Plenty of dupes.

Comment: @juanchopanza I am indeed using the -std=c++11 flag.
Most of the dupes are related to minGW and i'm not

Comment: Can you post a minimal but complete code sample, plus the complete compilation line?

Comment: What your code is "like" isn't helpful. Show what your code *is*. Copy and paste.

Comment: @RobKennedy If I post all the code in here it will get messy

Comment: Then reduce it. But it still needs to be valid. I can't paste your current code into my environment and get the results you report.

Comment: If I compile this code in the machine I described I do indeed get that error

Comment: @Rebirth To be pedantic, you can't compile the code you posted in the question, the code block needs to be placed in `int main()`.

Comment: @remyabel Alright, I added the complete compilable code

Comment: @ReBirTH Are you able to compile any other c++ code using the standard library in 32 bit?

Comment: If your code reproduces the error, maybe you should report a bug to the maintainer of the gcc port on freebsd. It compiles in linux.

Comment: @VladimirF Yes I can compile other c++ code

Comment: @user2079303 I'm thinking that it might be my `libstdc++` that may be outdated, but I'm not sure

Comment: @rebirth If you are using a homebrew version of gcc, make sure that you are also using the homebrew `libstdc++`.